# Understand the problem of continuous subarray sum

Tags: java, algorithm

Here is the [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/continuous-subarray-sum/) of the continuous subarray sum, my question is that this problem expects `nums = [5, 0, 0, 0]` and `k = 3` to be a True, which means that there is a sub-array that is divisible by a factor of 3. I fail to understand how it is so, for me it is clearly false, however all the submission returns true for this test. can anyone explain what I might be missing in here?

[image]

My solution:

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean checkSubarraySum(int[] nums, int k) {
        int sum = 0;
        int mod = 0;
        boolean isPresent = false;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i =0; i<nums.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + nums[i];
            mod = sum%k;
            if((mod==0 && i!=0) || (map.containsKey(mod) && (i - map.get(mod))>1)) {
                isPresent = true;
                break;
            }
            map.put(mod, i);
        }
        return isPresent;
    }
}
```

Comment: 0 is divisible by 3, which is why the sub array [0,0] meets the criteria of returning true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Solution

You have a neat solution. Just a little modification should solve the problem. But, first of all there should be no objection to the fact that `[0, 0]` is a subarray that is visible by any given `k`. Actually, your solution can cover such cases too, with just one modification:

```java
if(map.get(mod) == null) map.put(mod, i);
```

Alternatively

```java
map.putIfAbsent(mod, i);
```

##### Reasoning

If a mod is present in the map, we shouldn't update it unnecessarily. It may lead to an error in cases like `nums = [5, 0, 0, 0]` and `k = 3`. Here is how: 
For each iteration these are the variables: 
at `i` = 0   -->  at the end put (5, 0) to the map. 
at `i` = 1 --> at the end put (5, 1) to the map. 
at `i` = 2 --> at the end put (5, 2) to the map. 
at `i` = 3 --> at the end put (5, 3) to the map. 
In each step, you update the (mod, i) pair. As a result, `(i - map.get(mod))>1)` always gives `false`. Not updating the corresponding `i` value if the `mod` is already present in the map should solve the problem.

One might argue why not get rid of `(i - map.get(mod))>1)` part? 
Well because it's used for cases like:
`nums = [1,0]` and `key = 2`.

##### Extra

Your code takes `33 ms` for runtime and approximately `128 MB` for memory. With just one little modification, you can make it much better. 
Just get rid of the `isPresent` variable and return `true` in the `if` condition. Return `false` outside the `for loop`.
With these, on Leetcode it takes `17 ms` to complete and `54 MB` approximately. Exact numbers might vary from computer to computer.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the subarray [0,0,0] the sum is 0 and 0 is divisible by any integer.

The problem with your implementation is, that it's subarrays can only start at the first element. When you add a second for-loop around your current loop that changes the start-element, you will find a solution.